# HTML5 - Placing a Design of a Wide Banner in The Center of the Page With Different Gradient Colors

Tags: html, css

Our graphical designer created a home page design which contains a central banner with text and buttons to be placed in the center of our site which should occupies 100% width of the page.

The banner is divided to three parts the "real" content (in the middle) and the left side and the right side which should be stretched dynamically and contains different gradients colors.

When trying to place it, I cropped the middle of the banner and in-order to center it I used this code:

```
                  <div style="background-image: url('/images/WideBannerBG.png') ;width:1100px ;margin: 0px auto ;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:415px" >
```

Which works fine.

To set the left and right sides of the banner I cropped two thin vertical lines (1/415) and using HTML placed a code to repeat it horizontally thus filling the left and right gaps dynamically (according to the page resolution) - and failed doing so... here is the code

```
    <div style="width: 100%; overflow:hidden ">
         <div style="float:right;background-image: url('/images/WideBannerLeftStripe.png');width:100%;background-repeat:repeat-x;height:415px"> </div>          

                    <div style="background-image: url('/images/WideBannerBG.png') ;width:1100px ;margin: 0px auto ;background-repeat:no-repeat;height:415px" > ....
 ...
...</div>
         <div style="float:right;background-image: url('/images/WideBannerRightStripe.png');width:100%;background-repeat:repeat-x;height:415px"> </div>         
</div>
```

Here is the banner (w/o the text and site related things).

[image]

Are you familiar with any way to center a fixed size DIV (or table) and have different backgrounds on the left & right side which dynamically stretched (using repeat-x) according to screen resolution?

Comment: Er, what's your question?

Comment: I just edited the question to better clarify my question which is:
Are you familiar with any way to center a fixed size DIV (or table) and have different backgrounds on the left & right side which dynamically stretched (using repeat-x) according to screen resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stack multiple backgrounds using CSS3, just separate each background declaration with a comma. Then position them using the `background-position` property. To the top (0) and the left (0), and for the second background 50% from the left and the top (0).

Then use background size to make them stretch the height of the div (100%) and 50% width each.

```
.multi-background {
   background-image: url(WideBannerLeftStripe.png), url(WideBannerRightStripe.png);
   background-position: 0 0, 50% 0;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100% 50%, 100% 50%;
{
```